# Ajax: the script does not send data using the POST method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> EDIT

I modified the script this way, but the data is not transmitted through the POST method

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#min_price').change(function(){  
       var price = $(this).val();  
       $("#price_range").text("Product under EUR." + price);  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"/loading-price-range.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{price:price},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $("#product_loading").fadeIn(500).html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  
 });
```

It is a simple Ajax script to send, with the post method, a value (product price) obtained from a sliding prices.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="55000" step="200" value="0" id="min_price" name="min_price" />
<span id="price_range"></span>
```

It would seem that the script works regularly, because `#product_loading` is called correctly and the page updates, even if it does not show any data.

In "loading-price-range.php", I have the following code `$price = isset ($ _ POST [" price "]);` that with echo does not give me anything back.

Comment: Change `data: "price=" + price` to `data: {price : price}`. And remove all the spaces from this: `$ _ POST [" price "]`.

Comment: remove  dataType: "html",  . and try again

Comment: dateType is only what the .ajax is expecting to receive. Has NOTHING TO DO with sending data. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So what do you see in the Ajax call when you look at it in the network tab?

Comment: Use of `isset()` is incorrect. You are making value of `$price` a boolean, not the posted value

Comment: @charlietfl that too ;) Theres a lot of mistakes in this code all leading to the problem!

Comment: @IncredibleHat the string data vs object is actually perfectly valid

Comment: Hmm ... for some reason I had it in my head that when I had used that years ago, it was effy. Got into the habit of objects only for POST (for get its a different story). But it does appear to be 'aok' according to recent docs on the subject. However clearly, using isset() to transfer the $_POST variable is bad news here.

Comment: Can you inspect the POST request and include the header and request information in your post? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly post the data with `$.post()`, but I don't believe this is where your issue lies.

It looks like your PHP has some wonky formatting.

Try throwing a `print_r($_POST); exit;` at the start of your PHP. What do you get? I suspect all the data you're posting is there.

Comment: Only Array () is printed.

Comment: How are you testing? Are you navigating directly to the PHP script or are you inspecting the network traffic after your ajax code runs?

Comment: I set the "print_r" at the beginning of the answer php page. To understand, in loading-price-range.php

Comment: Yes, that's working correct. If you navigate directly to the php file, you should only see `Array ()` because you aren't posting anything. You need to inspect the POST request sent by ajax to get anything of value

Comment: I ran "print_r ($ _ POST ["price"]); exit;" but nothing ... nothing is printed. I can not understand why the price value is not transmitted to the page loading-price-range.php.